# Change IPSec IKEV2 VPN Default Ports 500 & 4500 To Anothers

Tags: centos, certificates, strongswan, letsencrypt

For some reason OpenVPN is working on my local machine very well, But IPSec IKEV2 VPN not & it only works when OpenVPN is connect.
I have a domain for IPSec IKEV2 VPN & in local machine vpn is using port 443.
Tell what should i do to force vpn workable on my local machine without OpenVPN.
Should i change port 443 on server or change ports 500 & 4500?

---

I followed the link below for setup IKEv2 VPN Using Strongswan and Let's encrypt on CentOS 7 With Some Changes.

[How to Setup IKEv2 VPN Using Strongswan and Let's encrypt on CentOS 7](https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-setup-ikev2-vpn-using-strongswan-and-letsencrypt-on-centos-7/)

My Let's encrypt commands is like this :

```
curl https://get.acme.sh | sh
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --set-default-ca --server letsencrypt
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --register-account -m helius.dev@gmail.com
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --standalone --force
service httpd stop
~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --issue -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --standalone --force

Your cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/my_domain.com.cer
Your cert key is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/my_domain.com.key
The intermediate CA cert is in: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/ca.cer
And the full chain certs is there: /root/.acme.sh/my_domain.com/fullchain.cer

~/.acme.sh/acme.sh --installcert -d my_domain.com --keylength 4096 --key-file /root/private.key --fullchain-file /root/cert.crt

service httpd start
service httpd status
```

Certificate Copy :

```
sudo cp /root/private.key /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/private/
sudo cp /root/cert.crt /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/certs/
sudo cp /root/.acme.sh/p02.artemis-art.buzz/ca.cer /etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/cacerts/
```

StrongSwan config :

```
#global configuration IPsec
#chron logger
config setup
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"
    uniqueids=no

#define new ipsec connection
conn hakase-vpn
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    ike=aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes256-aes128-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes256-sha1-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes128gcm12-sha256-sha1-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,3des-sha1-modp1024!
    esp=aes128-aes256-sha1-sha256-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128-sha1,aes128-sha1-modp1024,aes128-sha1-modp1536,aes128-sha1-modp2048,aes128-sha256,aes128-sha256-ecp256,aes128-sha256-modp1024,aes128-sha256-modp1536,aes128-sha256-modp2048,aes128gcm12-aes128gcm16-aes256gcm12-aes256gcm16-modp2048-modp4096-modp1024,aes128gcm16,aes128gcm16-ecp256,aes256-sha1,aes256-sha256,aes256-sha256-modp1024,aes256-sha256-modp1536,aes256-sha256-modp2048,aes256-sha256-modp4096,aes256-sha384,aes256-sha384-ecp384,aes256-sha384-modp1024,aes256-sha384-modp1536,aes256-sha384-modp2048,aes256-sha384-modp4096,aes256gcm16,aes256gcm16-ecp384,3des-sha1!
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes
    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s
    rekey=no
    left=%any
    leftid=@my_domain.com
    leftcert=cert.crt
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=eap-mschapv2
    rightsourceip=10.15.1.0/24
    rightdns=1.1.1.1,8.8.8.8
    rightsendcert=never
    eap_identity=%identity
```

And here is secrets file :

```
nano -K /etc/strongswan/ipsec.secrets

: RSA "private.key"
test : EAP "123"
```

---

Let explain problem again.
Some firewall rules on my wi-fi internet provider are blocking vpn (ikev2 - l2tp - pptp)
But openvps works like a charm.
When openvpn is working i can connect to ikev2 vpn by upper config.
Tell me what should i change about ikev2 to work whithout openvpn.
Fist step i think i should chanage ports 500 & 4500 on server.
I am right?
But how?
**/etc/strongswan/ipsec.d/** This file has no place for define custom ports!!!

Comment: Please provide your configurations (without passwords!) and include a description of what happens or doesn't happen when you start your IPsec VPN. Tell us both when it works with openvpn and when it doesn't

Comment: I did it. journalctl -fu strongswan on server shows activity of strongswan. When openvpn is connect and try to connect to ikev2 that log starts to show. But when openvpn is off that log shows nothing. > It is related to firewall of my wi-fi internet provider.